# /Zc:threadSafeInit flag in VS 2015

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, compiler-options

VS 2015 has a new flag `/Zc:threadSafeInit` that directs the compiler to generate code to make function local statics thread safe. However, I am unable to get this directive to take effect in my IDE. If I set it as Additional Options in the compiler command line property sheet, I get the following warning during build:

1>cl : Command line warning D9025: overriding '/Zc:threadSafeInit' with '/Zc:threadSafeInit-'

I don't see any instance of the latter anywhere in my project property sheets or .vcxproj files.

Anybody can guess what is going on here? Is there a possibility /Zc:threadSafeInit is conflicting with some other compiler option?

Comment: I'm not able to repro with VC++ 2015 Update 2.

Comment: Thread-safe initialization of function-local statics is [enabled by default](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5f6w579.aspx). Why do you need the option?

Comment: Works fine when I try it.  Check your toolset selection, ensure you have the latest update, just don't bother because it is the default as demanded by the C++ spec.

Comment: @HansPassant I understand its enabled by default. I went down this road only because **by default** I started getting tons of warnings about local statics being thread un-safe (both in the std library and in my code). In trying to shut this warning down, I introduced the /Zc:threadSafeInit flag manually, only to end up with that D9025 warning. I am about ready to commit myself to an asylum now.